# Livewire model with relations: Cannot read properties of null

Tags: laravel-livewire, laravel-livewire-wiremodel

What's wrong? I've Laravel 10, Livewire 3.

component:

```
public function mount()
{
  $this->post = \App\Models\Post::with('comments')->find(1);
}
```

template:

```
<div>
  @foreach($post->comments as $index => $comment)
    <div wire:key="comment-{{ $comment->id }}">
      <input type="text" wire:model="post.comments.{{ $index }}.text">
      <pre>{{ print_r($comment) }}</pre> {{-- <- Works fine --}}
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

I get an js error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'comments')`

I have no idea. I need help.

Comment: Is `$post` a `public` property?